# Is any risk when i try to update a mysql server's charset from utf8 to utf8mb4?

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

Include changing databases' or tables' or columns charset to utf8mb4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going the other way (from utf8mb4 to utf8) - According to [mysql`s manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) the risk is if your fields contain 'supplementary' characters. Otherwise they should be identical.
Looks like there should be no risks going the way you intend.